# Assist with dict comprehension

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to write a dictionary comprehension.

I have a dictionary like this one:

```
main_dict = {
    'A' : {'key1' : 'valueA1', 'key2' : 'valueA2'},
    'B' : {'key2' : 'valueB2', 'key3' : 'valueB3'},
    'C' : {'key3' : 'valueC3', 'key1' : 'valueC1'}}
```

I want to perform the following logic:

```
d = {}
for k_outer, v_outer in main_dict.items():
    for k_inner, v_inner in v_outer.items():
        if k_inner in d.keys():
            d[k_inner].append([k_outer, v_inner])
        else:
            d[k_inner] = [[k_outer, v_inner]]
```

Which yields the following result:

```
{'key3': [['C', 'valueC3'], ['B', 'valueB3']], 
 'key2': [['A', 'valueA2'], ['B', 'valueB2']], 
 'key1': [['A', 'valueA1'], ['C', 'valueC1']]}
```

(I know I could use `defaultdict(list)` but this is just an example)

I want to perform the logic using a dict-comprehension, so far I have the following:

```
d = {k : [m, v] for m, x in main_dict.items() for k, v in x.items()}
```

This does not work, it only gives me the following output:

```
{'key3' : ['B', 'valueB3'],
'key2' : ['B', 'valueB2'],
'key1' : ['C', 'valueC1']}
```

Which is the last instance found for each inner_key...

I am at a loss of how to perform this nested list-comprehension correctly. I have tried multiple variations, all worse than the last.

Comment: For clarity, could you show us the output you're expecting for your example input?

Comment: Are you sure putting all of this logic in a dict comprehension is a good idea? Sometimes readability is better than few lines of code.

Comment: @PeterStahl You clearly haven't played [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) before

Comment: @AlexL Well, if it's just for the sake of playing golf, then it's okay. ;)

Comment: Why is this tagged "performance"? Are you trying to get the fastest version, or the version that uses the least temporary memory?

Comment: @abarnert The reason I am not simply using the code I already posted is that I need to do this for large amounts of data, and numerous times for different data sets. And so, performance on all fields is important, it is both time-critical and must be memory-efficient.

Comment: @InbarRose: In that case, you really should have written "What's the fastest way to do this?" rather than "How do I do this with a dictionary comprehension?"; that's why half the answers are "You shouldn't use a comprehension here, for readability's sake", and the other half are code golf. But at least you can `timeit` each of the answers and see if anything helps.

Comment: @InbarRose: Meanwhile, how large is "large amounts of data"? Large enough that maybe `anydbm`, `shelve`, or even `sqlite3` might be drastically more efficient than a bunch of `dict`s?

Comment: @abarnert Well, the code I am writing receives its data in dictionary form. so either way I have to deal with dictionaries, I could however take the data and do what I wanted, as long as I get the result I need. In this case, I need a list of `[(Inner_key, [(Outer_Key, Value), ...]), ...]` which is pretty much a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, this is what i used:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for m, x in main_dict.items():
    for k, v in x.items():
        d[k].append((m, v))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
In [61]: main_dict
Out[61]: 
{'A': {'key1': 'valueA1', 'key2': 'valueA2'},
 'B': {'key2': 'valueB2', 'key3': 'valueB3'},
 'C': {'key1': 'valueC1', 'key3': 'valueC3'}}

In [62]: keys=set(chain(*[x for x in main_dict.values()]))

In [64]: keys
Out[64]: set(['key3', 'key2', 'key1'])

In [63]: {x:[[y,main_dict[y][x]] for y in main_dict if x in main_dict[y]] for x in keys}
Out[63]: 
{'key1': [['A', 'valueA1'], ['C', 'valueC1']],
 'key2': [['A', 'valueA2'], ['B', 'valueB2']],
 'key3': [['C', 'valueC3'], ['B', 'valueB3']]}
```

A more readable solution using `dict.setdefault`:

```
In [81]: d={}

In [82]: for x in keys:
    for y in main_dict:
       if x in main_dict[y]:
           d.setdefault(x,[]).append([y,main_dict[y][x]])
   ....:            

In [83]: d
Out[83]: 
{'key1': [['A', 'valueA1'], ['C', 'valueC1']],
 'key2': [['A', 'valueA2'], ['B', 'valueB2']],
 'key3': [['C', 'valueC3'], ['B', 'valueB3']]}
```

Comment: In other words, leave it as loops.

Comment: This is an interesting idea - to extract the keys first, it could all be done in one line, but it would still mean iterating over the `main_dict` keys twice. Whereas the 'long' method I posted above does the whole thing in one pass. I am certain there is a way to do it using dict-comprehension and one-pass efficiently, just need to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Using three dictionary comprehensions to achieve such task, the third dict-comprehension is to combine the first two dicts:

```
e = {k : [m, v] for m, x in main_dict.items() for k, v in x.items()}
f = {k : [m, v] for m, x in main_dict.items() for k, v in x.items() if [m,v] not in e.values()}
g = {k1 : [m, v] for k1,m in e.items() for k2,v in f.items() if k1==k2}
```

Comment: You _could_ combine this whole thing into one massive nested comprehension, of course, if you really want to make it impossible for anyone to ever read again. :)

Comment: I write this just to show a pythonic way and the subtlety of dict-comprehension.

Comment: The sample dictionary I posted is just a sample/example, the real dictionary has many more entries, This solution would not work - and if it were to be adapted (i.e. more dictionaries for each entry) it would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

main_dict = {
    'A' : {'key1' : 'valueA1', 'key2' : 'valueA2'},
    'B' : {'key2' : 'valueB2', 'key3' : 'valueB3'},
    'C' : {'key3' : 'valueC3', 'key1' : 'valueC1'}}

## Pull inner key, outer key and value and sort by key (prior to grouping)
x = sorted([(k2, [k1, v2]) for k1, v1 in main_dict.items() for k2, v2, in v1.items()])

## Group by key. This creates an itertools.groupby object that can be iterated
## to get key and value iterables
xx = groupby(x, key=itemgetter(0))

for k, g in xx:
    print('{0} : {1}'.format(k, [r[1] for r in list(g)]))
```

Depending on your data and performance requirements, sorting may not be ideal so it's worth profiling.

Further, it does not result in a dict as specified, but a groupby object. That might be 'dict-like' enough for your needs; Iterating it yields key and iterables.

Comment: But how can I use this data structure like a dictionary?

Comment: Either by iterating is as shown and using the key & value list as required, or by iterating it and putting it into a dict. If you really do need a dict, perhaps this isn't an appropriate solution.